# Prevent Ctrl-D from moving to next mail when reaching bottom of email in mutt pager

Tags: email, mutt

I have the following keybindings in my muttrc (among others).

```
bind generic,index,pager \Cf            next-page
bind generic,index,pager \Cb            previous-page
bind generic,index,pager \Cd            half-down
bind generic,index,pager \Cu            half-up
```

I have been trying to get a vim-like key-binding in mutt and as a part of that, I'd like Ctrl-D and Ctrl-U to work as page-up/page-down globally. When reading an email, this works just fine except that when I've reached the end of the email (by hitting enough number Ctrl-Ds), an additional Ctrl-D moves me to the next email in the mailbox.

I would like it stop there and show "Bottom of message is shown" consistent to "Top of message is shown" when I try to page-up beyond the top of the email. This looks like the "expected" default behaviour IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

Adding following line into your muttrc will serve Your needs.

```
set pager_stop = yes
```

---

#### References

From [muttrc(5)](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#pager-stop) / [neomuttrc(5)](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#3-238-%C2%A0pager_stop):

> pager_stop
>   Type: boolean
>   Default: no
>
> When set, the internal-pager will **not** move to the next message when you are at the end of a message and invoke the `<next-page>` function.